# The angle giving minimum value

Tags: trigonometry

We know minimum value of $\sin(x)+\cos(x)+\tan(x)+\cot(x)+\sec(x)+\csc(x)=6$ by AM-GM inequality. But I wanted to know whether manually can find out that angle $x$. Is it possible?

Comment: Equality holds when all $6$ of them are equal, and I doubt if that would happen. Also all $6$ of them have to be positive to use AM-GM.

Comment: Yes that's what I want to solve $...=..=..$

Comment: If $\sin x = \csc x$, then $|\sin x| = 1$, but $\cos x = 0$ at those values, and $\sec x$ is not even defined. So $6$ is not a tight lower bound of the sum, assuming you are talking about $x\in(0,\pi/2)$.

Comment: The minimum is [slightly bigger](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+sin%28x%29+%2B+cos%28x%29+%2B+tan%28x%29+%2B+sec%28x%29+%2B+csc%28x%29+%2B+cot%28x%29+for+x%3E0+and+x%3Cpi%2F2) than 6.

Comment: No AugSB just wanted to know if its posibble let minimum value be $6...$

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301800/find-the-minimum-value-of-sin-x-cos-x-tan-x-cot-x-sec-x-csc-x-for-real